# VBA Automation of Tableau Workbooks using CMD

Tags: vba, cmd, tableau-api

Currently we produce many reports which go to different geographies. We would like to filter certain geographies so that only relevant information is sent out. The software we use is Tableau Desktop and we currently have a VBA code that we run through CMD prompt to automate the production of pdf reports.

However, we are unable to produce a Tableau packaged workbook with this method. Has anyone tried anything similar? Any recommendations would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, you would like to be able to programatically create a packaged workbook given an existing workbook and its (file-based) data sources?

Comment: To automate download of a tableau report maybe you could use this command line tool https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd.htm I agree you should get the data from the DB but usually this is a situation of shadow IT right? Where you build horrible buggy automations because IT won't help (usually with mostly good reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Server has support for automated distribution of PDF reports starting in version 8. You could do it from the command line with previous versions.

The main way I know to get a similar effect with Tableau Desktop involves writing code to modify the .tbw files (i.e. generate a variation of the workbook for each targeted region. they are just XML files)

Realize if you do this that the XML format is not publically documented, changes between releases, and altering the files outside of Tableau is not supported (because they can't know what you changed). So be careful, make backups and look for other solutions. I'd advise only changing the original master copy of your workbooks using Tableau, and if you have a need to generate variations automatically with awk, perl, python, ruby etc, then only read from the master copy programmatically, never write. Realize the format will change with the next release.

Comment: Hi Alex, I've got code that pulls the xml information from the .twb file but how do I send a print command to print to pdf?